# Every row of a file is converted to a new file

Tags: linux, shell, awk, command-line, command

I have a file that contains four columns and 5000 rows. I want to make 5000 new files from this file so that each file has one row from the original file. Also, I want to name the new files according to the values in the 4th column.
Example: The following file (XXXX.txt) has four rows

File: XXXX.txt

```
1 315 4567 G1
1 212 345 G2
2 315 25674 G3
3 12 235673 G4
```

Expected New Files

File: G1

```
1 315 4567 G1
```

File: G2

```
1 212 345 G2
```

File: G3

```
2 315 25674 G3
```

File: G4

```
3 12 235673 G4
```

I have tried this command:

`awk '{print > $0}' < XXXX.txt`

This command makes new files as desired, but I am not able to name new files as per column4 of the original file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try by slightly change the `awk` script:

```
awk '{print > $4}' XXXX.txt
```

But be aware if in the source file there is row with same 4th column as other the end file will contain only the last row. You can try something like to avoid it:

```
awk '{print >> $4}' XXXX.txt
```

N.B. Do not run it more than once as this will add the records twice.

If you eventually get "too many open files" error you can use script like this to explicitly close the output file(s)

```
awk '{print >> $4;close($4)}' XXXX.txt
```

Comment: You may get a redirection error if null string is passed. A workaround could be `awk '/./{print > $NF}' < XXXX.txt`

Comment: @HatLess, there are many possible "may". Just let give OP a place for discussion :)

Comment: With that many records, you may get a "too many open files" error. `close($4)` after printing to it.

Comment: @glennjackman, AFAIK the output file (created with redirection) will be closed automatically on next iteration (next line). But will add it as one more option.

Comment: GNU awk leaves the file open: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html. My mawk man page says "Redirection opens file or command only once, subsequent redirections append to the already
       open stream."

Comment: Also the `>` redirection does not act like the shell's: it will append to the file after truncating it the first time (assuming the file does not need to be closed)

Comment: Thanks Romeo, it worked well. Cheers.

Comment: @MuhammadSajidTahir, if you are happy with one of the answers feel free to accept it (the tick on the left of the answer)

Comment: @glennjackman already mentioned this above but I think you may have missed his point: regarding `But be aware if in the source file there is row with same 4th column as other the end file will contain only the last row.` - no, the difference between `>` and `>>` in awk is what happens **the first time** awk tries to write to the file (append or overwrite) but on subsequent writes both constructs always append. It's like `while x; do echo y; done > file` vs `while x; do echo y; done >> file` in shell, not `while x; do echo y > file; done` vs `while x; do echo y >> file; done`

Comment: @EdMorton, please correct me if I am wrong, but to append in `awk` i will need not to close the files. But if I do not close them will get evidentially "too many open file". The last one is avoidable but need sysadmin intervention.

Comment: `to append in awk i will need not to close the files.` - yes, or use `>>` instead of `>`. Regarding `if I do not close them will get evidentially "too many open file"` - yes, unless you're using GNU awk and then it'll just slow down as it tries to internally manage all of the virtually open files.

Answer (score 2):

You are somewhat close.
`awk '{print > $0}'` is equivalent to `awk '{print $0 > $0}'`, which is easier to understand.

If you print a line to file called by your desired 4'th column ($4) instead of whole line ($0) then it's going to be correct.

```
awk '{print $0 > $4}'
```

Comment: See the discussion under [@Romeo's same answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/703396/133219).

Comment: Thank you Tansy, it worked. Magic